# Script to copy NEW content to a NEW Google sheets tab

Tags: forms, google-sheets, automation, copy

I would like to set up script to copy content from a Form Response spreadsheet into a new tab that can be edited, deleted, copied etc. I have used the following CSS to make this happen BUT every time a new response is reported, the entire sheet is copied, and I would like to only add the NEW entry information... is this possible?

`function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses');

let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('In Progress');

sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));
} `

I tried editing the last line of the above code:

`sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));`

But am not sure what the appropriate range of "new" information would be. I think it should be something about the new entries being copied to the new sheet last row +1...